# can someone explain the below Regular Expression?,

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```
var num="55+60" 
num.match(/[\d\.]+/g)
```

I understood, it's finding the digits globally, but i couldn't understand the '[]','+' and '.' parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\d` matches any digit from 0 to 9. `\.` matches a point i.e. period. `[]` lets you define a set of characters to match. `[]+` means match 1 or more of the characters in the square brackets.

`[\d\.]+` will match numbers such as "45" or "45.123" but also "45.123.456" and "45...123." which may or may not be intended to be matched.

Answer (score 0):

This means any digit or a dot between [].
and when you use it with + this means any digits or dot that repeated more than once.

https://regex101.com/

this is a regex playground. You can learn more in this site